# How to fix ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in browser with APACHE 2.4.25 server and PHP 7.2 on mac os x

Tags: apache, xdebug, symfony4, macos-sierra, php-7.2

I get this line in apache error_log when submitting a form with Symfony 4 and trying to send an email with SwiftMailer :

[core:notice] [pid 84] AH00052: child pid 4125 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Chrome browser is returning ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (blank page).

My local server version is Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) on mac os x Sierra.

A virtual host is configured.
I'm also running PHP 7.2.14 installed with Homebrew.

I've no idea on issue starting point.

Maybe this is the use of Xdebug (v2.7.1) but not really sure at all!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well ... try disabling xdebug and see if it will work that way. Maybe you have wrong Xdebug or it crashes (or causes crash) for some reason (a possibility based on your brief description).

Comment: You mean disabling extension in php.ini?

Comment: Correct, disable xdebug in php.ini (do not forget to restart web server so PHP reads new config) and see how it will behave now.